# Hyperledger Fabric invoking chaincode from Node.js using user artifacts generated by configtxgen. How?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

If I understand things correctly, Node.js client examples enroll users, create wallets and then utilize these newly generated identities to perform transactions. At the same time examples for fabric-tools/CLI utilize identities/users generated with configtxgen, there is no enrollment or wallet creation ongoing. I can make both of these examples running for my purposes.

What I miss is an example of using the configtxgen generated admins/users from Node.js client, creating wallet for them etc? Does such example exist? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply read from file, save into the wallet and continue the same way as before.

Declare or replace variables suitably:

```js
        let identity0;
        let wallet0 = new FileSystemWallet(wallet0Path);
        let exists0 = await wallet0.exists(wallet0ID);
        if (!exists0) {
            let user0CertPemRead = fs.readFileSync(user0CertPath).toString('utf8');
            let user0PrvKeyPemRead = fs.readFileSync(user0KeyPath).toString('utf8');
            identity0 = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(mspID0, user0CertPemRead, user0PrvKeyPemRead);
            await wallet0.import(wallet0ID, identity0);
        } else {
            identity0 = await wallet0.export(wallet0ID);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems simple. I'll try it!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make it work under read-only file system which does not allow to save files?

Comment: Strange environment... Use `InMemoryWallet` instead of `FileSystemWallet`. I've never done, but it works by sure. https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.InMemoryWallet.html